# how to fix geocoder plugin installation error?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I am trying to install geocoder: ^0.2.1 plugin in my project to search for different location in google map. but I am not able to install and getting following error..

The plugin `geocoder` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: Can you post the link to the package?

Answer (score 0):

[geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder/versions/0.2.1) has not yet been migrated to null safety and android V2 embedding.
You need to wait for author to update it, until then you can use the library github version which supports the v2 embedding

Please use this repo => https://github.com/nguyenxdat/flutter_geocoder

Import in `pubspec.yaml`

```
geocoder: git: url: https://github.com/nguyenxdat/flutter_geocoder.git ref: master
```

**Note:** It's better if you switch a well maintained library, see if these does your work [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) , [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)